# Laravel new project / project creation

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, composer-php

Im a newbie in Laravel. I just started and followed some instructions in YT to install Laravel. I happen to install all of the required apps but this error showed up when creating a new project. Please help [image: Error]

I was trying to make a new project

Comment: Laravel have their own documentation about new project installment as can be seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#your-first-laravel-project). The one you followed might be outdated or something.

Comment: It seems that dependencies of the project requiring php 7.2, and your installed php version is not compliant with the one requested. 
Firstly, check your composer.json in the require section it has to have php version specified. if specified version is different than that you have, install the one which is in the require.

Comment: laravel new proj --ignore-platform-reqs